# Css 3D Animation woking well on Chrome doesn't work on Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, transform, css-transforms

I'm building rotating cube with css transform3d features. 
It works fine on Chrome, but not on Safari and 
I can't see why it shows up as wrong way.

I created Plunker of this code so you can actually fix this problem. 
The ideal appearance of this code can be confirmed on Chrome and 
I want to make it looks exactly same as what happening on Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated for me including not only fixing code but 
also description of why it doesn't work.

The Code on Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/csvtleYoWvOFccm4idcP?p=preview

HTML

```
    <div class='welcome'>
        <div id='animating_cube'>
          <div class='face1'></div>
          <div class='face2'></div>
          <div class='face3'></div>
          <div class='face4'></div>
        </div>
        <div id='message'>
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <span>
            This is an animating cube.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.welcome #animating_cube {
  display: block;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: animatingCubeRotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: animatingCubeRotate 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.welcome #animating_cube .face1 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  -webkit-animation: keyframeForFace1 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: keyframeForFace1 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.welcome #animating_cube .face2 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  -webkit-animation: keyframeForFace2 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: keyframeForFace2 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.welcome #animating_cube .face3 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  -webkit-animation: keyframeForFace3 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: keyframeForFace3 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.welcome #animating_cube .face4 {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  -webkit-animation: keyframeForFace4 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  animation: keyframeForFace4 5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.welcome #animating_cube .face1 {
  background: #eeeeee;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}
.welcome #animating_cube .face2 {
  background: #cccccc;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(75px);
}
.welcome #animating_cube .face3 {
  background: #dddddd;
  transform: translateZ(74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(74px);
}
.welcome #animating_cube .face4 {
  background: #cccccc;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(75px);
}
.welcome #message {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  top: 70px;
}
.welcome #message h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.welcome #message span {
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatingCubeRotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animatingCubeRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-30deg) rotateY(-45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyframeForFace2 {
  0% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }

  100% {
    background: #bbbbbb;
  }
}

@keyframes keyframeForFace2 {
  0% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }

  100% {
    background: #bbbbbb;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes keyframeForFace3 {
  0% {
    background: #dddddd;
  }

  100% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }
}

@keyframes keyframeForFace3 {
  0% {
    background: #dddddd;
  }

  100% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes keyframeForFace4 {
  0% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }
  100% {
    background: #dddddd;
  }
}
@keyframes keyframeForFace4 {
  0% {
    background: #cccccc;
  }
  100% {
    background: #dddddd;
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Safari just needs `-webkit-transform-style` instead of `-transform-style`. I also added

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
```

to the text (`.welcome #message`) so it wouldn't intersect with the cube in Safari, since it doesn't in Chrome.

Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3MefAjQgocgRpaswsZLV?p=preview